# How to remove an install program from Windows lauched for each start?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, autostart

I'm facing a strange problem about Windows Server.
I installed SharePoint Server on my Windows Server Instance (it works well)

During the install step, the prerequisiteinstaller.exe install some components to Windows before installing SharePoint. This step required a restart then after reboot it relaunches the app to continue the process.

All components are installed however, each time I restart the server It launch the app again and again : 
[image]

So I want just to kill that definitly because all is already installed and configured with success. How to remove this program to auto start ?

Thanks !

Comment: Download `autoruns.exe` from Microsoft.  You can disable/remove entries from many places.

Comment: It works fine ! I just removed SharePoint Preparation Tool from Everything tab.